# If you fix a block with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```js
$(function(){   
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            var scrollVal = $(this).scrollTop();
            var adscrtop =$(".header").offset().top
        // 在 RWD 767以下不作動
            if(window.screen.width>767){
            if(scrollVal> adscrtop){
                $(".banner").css({"position":"fixed","top":"60px"});
            }else{
                $(".banner").css({"position": "static"});
            }
            }
        });
     });
```

```css
.header{
  max-width:768px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.nav{
    position: sticky;
    top:0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #f55c47;
    z-index:99;
  }
  .container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content:space-between;
}
.main{
      position: sticky;
      top:60px;
      flex:2;
      background-color: #9fe6a0;
      padding:10px;
}

.banner{
      flex:1;
      width: 200px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: #564a4a;
}
 .img{
        width: 100%;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
  <div class="nav"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="main">
      Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem quae maiores, quibusdam doloribus eum excepturi ab fugit dolor vel, est molestiae magni tenetur nihil, non architecto aperiam. Consectetur tempore atque doloribus exercitationem veniam. Quibusdam, odio nisi at similique magnam nobis, voluptates non iste laudantium in quo harum soluta voluptatibus vitae labore modi ullam minima enim placeat nesciunt assumenda perspiciatis cumque! A modi delectus assumenda totam, pariatur harum! Odio adipisci maxime expedita beatae hic vero natus necessitatibus! Error earum at natus nemo! Quae aliquid minima quasi exercitationem eum, iure rerum consequatur ipsa. Optio repellendus quibusdam quia incidunt accusamus beatae ex? Accusantium nam, enim esse fugit repellendus dignissimos amet reiciendis nulla porro quo quis facere unde nesciunt culpa molestias sunt a beatae non ad. Voluptatibus, velit numquam. Adipisci molestiae in commodi non officiis facilis repellendus, doloremque cupiditate dolorum nostrum neque magnam aut asperiores quo nam id optio facere nesciunt praesentium. Repellat provident vero rem, tempore ad possimus accusantium perferendis! Architecto repellendus, error numquam necessitatibus voluptatibus asperiores dolorem eius quos beatae a doloremque velit suscipit perspiciatis nisi in tempora illum quidem? In totam fugit mollitia libero sequi voluptates soluta praesentium dolor nihil! Magnam sunt animi omnis in repudiandae cum laudantium nemo unde nulla necessitatibus mollitia nihil accusantium hic voluptas ab facilis aperiam ipsum, natus suscipit corporis. Alias quidem beatae, dolore et recusandae nisi optio error laboriosam temporibus minima voluptatibus reiciendis ipsam officia expedita totam asperiores at provident? Rerum illo provident vitae asperiores optio. Quas est obcaecati consequuntur accusantium quasi possimus soluta architecto adipisci quisquam. Magni, suscipit, quisquam quasi iure architecto expedita reiciendis vitae nulla consequuntur ex illo. Nobis accusantium et eveniet animi, quibusdam sunt beatae consequatur error, qui impedit rerum exercitationem, nulla cupiditate distinctio? Repudiandae fuga excepturi hic ex unde sequi labore, nulla sapiente, distinctio tempora et, dignissimos fugiat inventore a nemo rerum maiores nihil soluta laudantium eius ipsa accusantium explicabo similique! Atque, iusto ipsam! Sequi, nam, laborum velit repellat perferendis voluptatem reprehenderit, odio commodi blanditiis doloremque corrupti quam in nesciunt! Culpa quam iure vero. Labore error, iure assumenda aliquam ea possimus! Amet aliquam eos maxime? Quos numquam quas similique ex eos  tempora magni repellendus praesentium? Ad quae vel labore quisquam quidem aliquam, molestias dolorum pariatur minus cupiditate odio, velit mollitia, deleniti corrupti eius nam, optio ullam impedit amet ducimus dolores architecto, id, quaerat ratione sed quas. Qui eius labore quia maiores adipisci, quos quod omnis veritatis modi fugiat. Et, cupiditate, cumque laudantium rem praesentium error odio veniam, repellat 
    </div>
    <div class="banner">
      <img class"photo"src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620706857370-e1b9770e8bb1?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=80" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Tonight try using jQuery to fix the brown block under the red block. When scrolling up, only the green block will go up!

The brown area is fixed below the red area, but there are some problems As I scroll up, the brown block goes to the left and goes behind the red block Would you like to help me see which side of my code I have written wrong? Which side did I get wrong? Thank you for watching my question.

PS. My English is not very good, please let me know if there is something wrong with my expression. Thank you. Below is my code`

Comment: You would need to provide a proper working snippet for us to be able to debug it. The current snippet only shows text.

Try editing the snippet and run it to check if you are able to show us the working example.

Comment: I'm sorry that I didn't fully present my problem. The code has been attached again. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

There is a small mistake here.

Inside your scroll listener, you have written `"position": "fixed"`.
Whereas it should've been `"position": "sticky"`.

```
$(".banner").css({
    "position": "sticky",
    "top": "60px"
});
```

`"position": "sticky"` automatically makes the element stick at the given position while scrolling.

For more info on CSS Positioning, check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) out.

Check the updated snippet

```js
$(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollVal = $(this).scrollTop();
    var adscrtop = $(".header").offset().top
    // 在 RWD 767以下不作動
    if (window.screen.width > 767) {
      if (scrollVal > adscrtop) {
        $(".banner").css({
          "position": "sticky",
          "top": "60px"
        });
      } else {
        $(".banner").css({
          "position": "static"
        });
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.header {
  max-width: 768px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #f55c47;
  z-index: 99;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.main {
  position: sticky;
  top: 60px;
  flex: 2;
  background-color: #9fe6a0;
  padding: 10px;
}

.banner {
  flex: 1;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #564a4a;
}

.img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
  <div class="nav"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="main">
      Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem quae maiores, quibusdam doloribus eum excepturi ab fugit dolor vel, est molestiae magni tenetur nihil, non architecto aperiam. Consectetur tempore atque doloribus exercitationem veniam.
      Quibusdam, odio nisi at similique magnam nobis, voluptates non iste laudantium in quo harum soluta voluptatibus vitae labore modi ullam minima enim placeat nesciunt assumenda perspiciatis cumque! A modi delectus assumenda totam, pariatur harum!
      Odio adipisci maxime expedita beatae hic vero natus necessitatibus! Error earum at natus nemo! Quae aliquid minima quasi exercitationem eum, iure rerum consequatur ipsa. Optio repellendus quibusdam quia incidunt accusamus beatae ex? Accusantium
      nam, enim esse fugit repellendus dignissimos amet reiciendis nulla porro quo quis facere unde nesciunt culpa molestias sunt a beatae non ad. Voluptatibus, velit numquam. Adipisci molestiae in commodi non officiis facilis repellendus, doloremque
      cupiditate dolorum nostrum neque magnam aut asperiores quo nam id optio facere nesciunt praesentium. Repellat provident vero rem, tempore ad possimus accusantium perferendis! Architecto repellendus, error numquam necessitatibus voluptatibus asperiores
      dolorem eius quos beatae a doloremque velit suscipit perspiciatis nisi in tempora illum quidem? In totam fugit mollitia libero sequi voluptates soluta praesentium dolor nihil! Magnam sunt animi omnis in repudiandae cum laudantium nemo unde nulla
      necessitatibus mollitia nihil accusantium hic voluptas ab facilis aperiam ipsum, natus suscipit corporis. Alias quidem beatae, dolore et recusandae nisi optio error laboriosam temporibus minima voluptatibus reiciendis ipsam officia expedita totam
      asperiores at provident? Rerum illo provident vitae asperiores optio. Quas est obcaecati consequuntur accusantium quasi possimus soluta architecto adipisci quisquam. Magni, suscipit, quisquam quasi iure architecto expedita reiciendis vitae nulla
      consequuntur ex illo. Nobis accusantium et eveniet animi, quibusdam sunt beatae consequatur error, qui impedit rerum exercitationem, nulla cupiditate distinctio? Repudiandae fuga excepturi hic ex unde sequi labore, nulla sapiente, distinctio tempora
      et, dignissimos fugiat inventore a nemo rerum maiores nihil soluta laudantium eius ipsa accusantium explicabo similique! Atque, iusto ipsam! Sequi, nam, laborum velit repellat perferendis voluptatem reprehenderit, odio commodi blanditiis doloremque
      corrupti quam in nesciunt! Culpa quam iure vero. Labore error, iure assumenda aliquam ea possimus! Amet aliquam eos maxime? Quos numquam quas similique ex eos tempora magni repellendus praesentium? Ad quae vel labore quisquam quidem aliquam, molestias
      dolorum pariatur minus cupiditate odio, velit mollitia, deleniti corrupti eius nam, optio ullam impedit amet ducimus dolores architecto, id, quaerat ratione sed quas. Qui eius labore quia maiores adipisci, quos quod omnis veritatis modi fugiat.
      Et, cupiditate, cumque laudantium rem praesentium error odio veniam, repellat
    </div>
    <div class="banner">
      <img class "photo"src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620706857370-e1b9770e8bb1?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=80" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer!
The reason why I didn't use this property is because in the project I was using position:sticky; Seems to be influenced by some element has been unable to achieve the effect!

Therefore, I changed to jQuery with fixed attribute to see if it can be achieved
I would like to ask whether fixed cannot be fixed in that place if fixed is insisted on?
Thank you.

Comment: Hi @WEIA. Having a `position: 'fixed'` means that the element is relative to the view port. So it will always overlap your text block. You wouldn't want this to happen. If you still want to use fixed, you would have to do a lot of hard coding. Do you want me to try to do it using `fixed` itself ?

Comment: Hello ~ Nisanth Reddy, thank you for your detailed explanation!
In this way, I know how to solve this problem. Thanks again for your help!